# Slow receiving of a JS file

Tags: html, apache, http, get, apache2

I have a strange problem and I just can't figure it out:
I'm including 2 .js files inside of the body. There is nothing else. First one is jQuery (32.4KB) which is downloaded from Google's servers and the second one is also jQuery (same file, 32.4KB) which is downloaded from my server.

And .js file from google is DLed like 5 time faster. And I'm talking just about the "receiving time." Not DNS lookup, connecting, waiting, etc, but plain receiving. I know that Google obviously has good connection but my (i.e. my server's) is not slow by any means - I get like 1MB(megabyte)/sec.

Here is the screenshot of firebug net graph: http://postimage.org/image/42dsog185/

I woudn't be worried if .js file from google would be DLed a bit faster, but 5 times?

Any ideas what could be wrong or how to look deeper into the problem to get the answer?

Thank you, Ed

Answer (score 0):

Google always serves their pages as gzip encoded if your browser supports it, which Firefox does. If your Apache server is not configured with `mod_deflate` then it will not compress the connection. Is it possible that this is the case?

You should check the headers that your server is sending. If it's not sending:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

then that explains the speed difference. Here's a [guide to configuring `mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Comment: Hi. No. I use mod_deflate too. As you can see file size is the same (32KB). If there wouldn't be any compression file would be around 90KB.

Comment: Firebug reports the size of the un-gzipped bytes transferred. The gzip encoding makes no difference to the value reported on that screen in Firebug. The headers are the only way to know whether it's gzipped. 90kb figure is the size of the un-minified jQuery, but you're clearly not using that one.

Comment: Thats simply not true - Minified jquery file is around 90KB. Not minified is around 300KB. Minified and compressed is around 32KB. And firebug shows gziped size.

Comment: Oops... you're right. I should have looked more carefully on the jQuery web site! Sorry!